Subnetting vs Firewalling
What is the point of subnetting from a security perspective, if all this seems to do is create additional processing in the router, hence latency?
It’s the firewall that allows or blocks traffic.
But then I know that you can’t ping a different host on another subnet. So subnetting creates a block all traffic condition. So it’s like a perfect firewall.
But then you see the internet work, so communication between subnets is very possible.
So it seems we have all these pieces which work a certain way that would suggest, that nothing should work.
Very confused.
I’ve read a computer networking book, so it’s not my first day of studying networking, but I’m obviously not there yet.
Anyone care to chime in to clear things up a bit?

Subnetting is a way to create larger network prefixes from a smaller network prefix. All IPv4 networks are a subnet of 0.0.0.0/0. That has nothing to do with firewalling. Routers are to route traffic between different networks (remember they are all subnets of 0.0.0.0/0). Firewalls are to protect networks.

Subnetting allows you to zone your network. If you put all your nodes in a single subnet you can't tell them apart, ie. have to rely on the IP address they claim to have.
Subnets can be grouped to security zones. Since a node cannot leave its subnet (if done correctly), it cannot leave its zone. Communication between subnets requires a gateway/router and that is exactly where you control the traffic.
If you route on intermediate L3 switches there's zero additional latency.

I know that you can’t ping a different host on another subnet.

Of course you can, if there's a route between the source and the destination, and there's no ICMP echo filtering.
You can ping across the Internet, can't you?

subnetting creates a block all traffic condition. So it’s like a perfect firewall.

Not at all.

Good points, food for thought.
